# Using Jasmine Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, gulp

I am writing some tests with [Jasmine](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine). I am running those tests via [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/). I want to use the [Jasmine Ajax](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine-ajax) plugin. However, I cannot figure out how to include it into my tests. Right now, I have the following:

**tests.js**

```
describe('MyApp', function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    jasmine.Ajax.install();
  });

  it('should run an ajax request', function() {
    // test ajax
  });
});
```

Once again, I'm running this via Gulp. So, in my gulpfile.js I have the following:

**gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var jasmine = require('gulp-jasmine');

gulp.task('test', function() {
  return gulp
    .src('tests/*.js')
    .pipe(jasmine());
});
```

When I execute this, I get the following from the command-line:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'install' of undefined.

Its like Jasmine Ajax isn't getting loaded. Yet, I'm not sure how to load it. Can someone please help me solve this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you installed jasmine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this myself since I don't have enough info to recreate your setup, but you could try to put the `mock-ajax.js` file in the `helpers` directory, that is where the [default configuration](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine-npm/blob/master/spec/support/jasmine.json) of jasmine-npm, which is used by gulp-jasmine, looks for them.